# OpenCV-2.1.0 and CMake2.8.2

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, cmake

When I try to press the `Configure` button at `CMake 2.8.2` after adding:

C:\Program Files\OpenCV-2.1.0 to `Where is the source code:`

And,

C:\Program Files\OpenCV-2.1.0\build to `Where to build the binaries:`

I get an error message stating the following:

`Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid`

I can also see the following messages:

`CMakeError: Unable to open cache file for save. C:\Program Files\OpenCV-2.1.0\build\CMakeCache.txt`

`CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied`

`CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied`

Provided that I don't have `CMakeCache.txt` inside the `build` directory.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use the most recent version of OpenCV, version 2.3?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010_CMake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied" means that you don't have write access to the folder "C:\Program Files\OpenCV-2.1.0\build".

Just change to a different folder. Use a folder where you do have write access / privileges for the "Where to build the binaries:" location...